# How can I display the `\gtrsymBorn` symbol in red colour?

Tags: color, genealogytree, option-clash

How can I display the `\gtrsymBorn` symbol in red colour? he following MWE returns `LaTeX Error: Option clash for package xcolor.`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{genealogytree}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\color{Red}{Text \gtrsymBorn}

\end{document}
```

Comment: remove `\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}` then use `red` not `Red` ?

Comment: in a current tex system it will not error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See section 9.1.2 in the manual of `genealogytree`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{genealogytree}

\begin{document}

{\gtrSymbolsSetCreate{Red}\gtrsymBorn}
\gtrsymBorn{}
{\gtrSymbolsSetCreate{red}\gtrsymBorn}

\end{document}
```

I loaded `xcolor` before `genealogytree` which used to be needed (nowadays it isn't). Alternatively you can do

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames]{article}
\usepackage{genealogytree}

\begin{document}

{\gtrSymbolsSetCreate{Red}\gtrsymBorn}
\gtrsymBorn{}
{\gtrSymbolsSetCreate{red}\gtrsymBorn}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that `genealogytree` doesn't by default make its symbols to respect the current color. But you can redefine them to do it. I'm afraid you need to pass a list of the symbol names you want to make “current color aware”.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{genealogytree}
\gtruselibrary{templates}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\colorizegtrsymbols}{m}
 {
  \clist_map_function:nN { #1 } \__stucke_colorize:n
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__stucke_colorize:n
 {% genealogytree symbols are simple macros
  \cs_set_eq:cc { __stucke_colorize_#1: } { #1 }
  \ExpandArgs{c}\RenewDocumentCommand{#1}{}
   {
    \gtrSymbolsSetCreate{.}\use:c { __stucke_colorize_#1: }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

% make some symbols “color aware”, add to the list
\colorizegtrsymbols{gtrsymBorn,gtrsymDied}

\begin{document}

Text \gtrsymBorn{} \gtrsymDied{}

\textcolor{Red}{Text \gtrsymBorn{} \gtrsymDied{}}

\begin{tikzpicture} \genealogytree[template=signpost,timeflow=left,level size=3cm]
{
  parent[id=DoeJones]{
    g[id=Deir2012,female]{Deirdre\\\gtrsymBorn\,2012}
    parent[id=Jones]{
      g[id=Mary1988,female]{Aunt Mary\\\gtrsymBorn\,1988}
      p[id=JimJ1944,male]{\color{Red}Jim Jones\\\gtrsymDied\,1944}
      % the following node is going to be ignored
      p[ignore,id=Jenn1949,female]{Jenny Jones\\\gtrsymBorn\,1949}
    }
  }
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I took an example from the package documentation to show that, at least in this experiment, the colors are as expected. Augment the list to your pleasure.

[image]